# assining a menu for each type of users with jsf

Tags: templates, jsf, menu, javabeans

i'm trying to include a menu in a template that's used in my web pages, the thing is that my menu changes according to wich type of users is connected. oh and i'm using jsf.
so page->template->menu 
in the first page login.xhtml a button takes the user to the bean:

```
<p:commandButton id="logins"  value="login"  action="#{UtilisateurBean.connection_role}"  update="growl"/>
```

in the utilisateurBean the methode connection_role looks like this:

```
public String connection_role() {
    Utilisateur authentifi = resp.seConnecter_role(login, password, typeRole);
    FacesMessage msg;
    FacesContext myFacesContext;

    if ("_".equals(authentifi.getLogin())) {
        msg = new FacesMessage("Compte incorrect", "Login password incorrect");
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);

        myFacesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        myFacesContext.addMessage(null, msg);

        return null;
    } else if (authentifi != null) {
        Utilisateur user = resp.findById(idutilisateur);
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        if (typeRole.equals("Administrateur")) {
            cleanForm();
            setMenu("menuAdministrateur.html");
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            return "listItem.xhtml";
        } else if (typeRole.equals("Administrateur Audit")) {
            cleanForm();
            setMenu("menuAdministrateurAudit.html");
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            return "Administrateur_Audit";
        } else if (typeRole.equals("Planificateur")) {
            cleanForm();
            setMenu("menuPlanificateur.html");
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            return "Planificateur";
        } else {
            cleanForm();
            setMenu("menuAuditeur.html");
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            return "Auditeur";
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

in my template i'v put :

now when i click on the login button the page thasn't go anywhere, the user is connected i'v cheked that with some printlns but no calling any other page.

Ps: if i replace  `<ui:insert name="#{UtilisateurBean.menu}" ></ui:insert>`
with  `<ui:insert name="menuAuditeur.xhtml" ></ui:insert>`
 it works just fine and the new page shows up

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the `<ui:insert...` with `<h:panelGroup id="myPanel"...` and in your `<p:commandButton` add the `myPanel id` to the list of elements to update? Like `<p:commandButton update="growl, myPanel"` .... ?

In case a form with id surrounds the `<ui:insert` you should do something like `<p:commandButton update="growl, form1Id:myPanel`

?

Comment: well the <ui:insert.... is in the Template.xhtml and the <p:commandButton is in the login.xhtml page (wich calls the Template.xhtml) so the <p:commandButton... wouldn't know the myPanel.                                                         Actually i replaced the <ui:insert with  <ui:include src="#{UtilisateurBean.menu}"></ui:include> and it's okey now my menus change depending on who is connected, but i noticed that the content of the pages deaspears, text , datatables. I'm still looking into it could it be because of the include???        and thank you for answering :)

Comment: Havent noticed its insert instead of include... anyway it should see the wrapping panelgroup... its all ends up in the aame page